# Unable to display the spamProbabilityChart in HTML using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm working on a web application that performs email analysis and displays various visualizations, including a chart to represent the spam probability. However, I'm encountering an issue where the spamProbabilityChart is not being displayed on the page.

Here's my relevant HTML code:

```
     <div id="result-box-section" class="result box">
         <!-- Content exists here -->
         <h5 id="spam-probability">Spam Probability: {{ percentage }} %</h5>
         <h5>Word Count: {{ result }}</h5>
         <br />
         <h5>Emotional Analysis:</h5>
         <canvas id="emotionAnalysisChart"></canvas>
     </div>
```

And here's the JavaScript code that should create and populate the chart -

analyzeEmail Function:

```
function analyzeEmail() {
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var analyzeBtn = document.getElementById("analyze-btn");
            // Add the loading animation class
            analyzeBtn.value = 'Loading...';
            analyzeBtn.disabled = true;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/predict", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    var resultBoxSection = document.getElementById("result-box-section");
                    var predictionText =
                        response.prediction[0] === 1
                            ? '<span style="color: red;">Spam</span>'
                            : '<span style="color: green;">Not Spam</span>';
                    var spamProbability = response.percentage;
                    var wordCount = response.result;
                    var emoData = response.emo_data;
                    // Update the HTML content
                    resultBoxSection.innerHTML =
                        "<h5>Prediction: " +
                        predictionText +
                        "</h5>" +
                        "<h5>Spam Probability: " + spamProbability + "%</h5>" +
                        "<h5>Word Count: " + wordCount + "</h5>" +
                        "<br>" +
                        "<h5>Emotional Analysis:</h5>" +
                        "<canvas id='emoChart'></canvas>";
                    // Remove the loading animation class
                    analyzeBtn.value = 'Analyze';
                    analyzeBtn.disabled = false;
                    // Create the chart
                    createEmoChart(emoData);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: email }));
        }
```

Graph function:

```
function createSpamProbabilityChart(spamProbability) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("spamProbabilityChart").getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "horizontalBar",
                data: {
                    labels: ["Spam Probability"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Probability",
                        data: [spamProbability],
                        backgroundColor: "#21c9d4",
                        barThickness: 10,
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100,
                                callback: function (value) {
                                    return value + "%";
                                }
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "Probability",
                                fontColor: "#000",
                                fontSize: 12,
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

emoGraph: (This is being displayed)

```
function createEmoChart(emoData) {
            var labels = emoData.map(function (data) {
                return data[0];
            });
            var scores = emoData.map(function (data) {
                return data[1];
            });
            // Define an array of colors for each emotion label
            var colors = ['#FF9AFF', '#CCFF99', '#FFA954', '#FF7878', '#A2CDFF', '#7DFF7D', '#5DA5A5', '#724BA3'];
            var ctx = document.getElementById("emoChart").getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "pie",
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Score",
                        data: scores,
                        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0, labels.length)
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true
                }
            });
        }
```

The createSpamProbabilityChart function is not being executed, and as a result, the chart is not displayed. I've verified that the analyzeEmail function is successfully invoked and the spamProbability value is available. (FYI - The other graph is being displayed)

I've already ensured that I have included the necessary Chart.js library in my project.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the createSpamProbabilityChart function is not being called and how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Image:

[image: Graph not being shown]

Comment: Well, where *do*  you call `createSpamProbabilityChart`? How are we supposed to know why the function is not executed if you don't show the code that is supposed to call it?